# Job deliver, apply, revision, accept system with php, javascript, and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

**This is lengthy, so please bear with me!**

I am working on a project where user can post and apply to jobs. More than 1 user can also apply to the same job.

I have created 4 tables for this:

**Jobs** : when someone posts a job I am inserting jobs in this table.

```
+--------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+--------+
| job_id | posted_by | job_desc | workers_needed | delivery_time | job_expiration      | status |
+========+===========+==========+================+===============+=====================+========+
| CURSSF | 595959    | Some Job | 6              | 1 Day         | 2020-05-14 05:19:44 | active |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+--------+
```

**Job_applicants**: this is where I enter data when someone applies to the job

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
| job_id  | posted_by | applicant_id | date_applied | job_expiration | status      |
+=========+===========+==============+==============+================+=============+
| CURZTJW | 5918624   | 120757654    | 1589349555   | 1589349555     | in_progress |
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
```

**Job_deliveries**: when someone deliver the job I insert it in this table.

```
+--------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| job_id | applicant_id | delivery_text | status                | delivered_at |
+========+==============+===============+=======================+==============+
| CURSSF | 595959       | Some Text     | waiting_for_approval | 1589357456   |
+--------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

**Job_revisions**: if the buyer needs a revision this where I insert it.

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| job_id | delivery_id | applicant_id | revision_text | requested_at |
+========+=============+==============+===============+==============+
| CURSSF | 595954      | 451854185    | Some Text     | 1589357456   |
+--------+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

I have create a job_deliver page where I am showing a timer and deliver job button to workers. right now the user can post, apply, and deliver jobs.

**Here is where it gets complicated:**

I want to show all the deliveries to the buyers with the option of Accept and Request revision. if buyer accepts I want to mark the job as completed the job and add review to user profile. if he asks for a revision I want to show that to the worker and he will the deliver the job again.

**What I have tried:**

please note: I have used prepared statements for every sql query.

First I have fetched all the deliveries for the open job with job id.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM job_deliveries WHERE status = ? AND job_id = ?";` like so.

then showing all the deliveries with a loop.

```
while ($delivery = mysqli_fetch_assoc($deliveries)) {
 // code goes here >>>
}
```

I have created 2 buttons inside the loop for the delivery. Accept and Request revision and with the jquery I am showing two different forms on click event.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary w-md waves-effect waves-light mb-2 mr-3" id="review_seller_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>">Accept & Review Job</button>

<div class="review_seller mt-4" id="accept_review_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 pl-0">

        <h4 class="font-22 font-700 m-0 mb-2">Public Feedback</h4>

        <form action="job_deliver?job=<?php echo $_GET['job']; ?>" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="user_rating" value="">

            <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['job']; ?>">

            <input type="hidden" name="delivery_id" value="<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>">

            <input type="hidden" name="freelancer" value="<?php echo $delivery['applicant_id']; ?>">

            <h4 class="font-16 font-600 m-0 my-2">What was it like working with <?php echo $seller_name ?>?</h4>

            <textarea name="review_text" id="review_text" placeholder="Did <?php echo $seller_name ?> help you achieve your goal?" cols="30" rows="3" required class="form-control <?php echo isset($errors['review']) ? 'form-error' : ''; ?>"></textarea>

            <div class="form-errors-list filled"><?php echo $errors['review'] ?? ''; ?></div>

            <button type="submit" name="accept-job-submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary w-md waves-effect waves-light float-right">
                <span id="btnLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span>
                <span id="btnText">Send Feedback</span>
            </button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-light w-md waves-effect waves-light mb-2" id="request_revision_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>">Request Revision</button>

<div class="revision_details mt-4" id="revision_details_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 pl-0">

        <form action="job_deliver?job=<?php echo $_GET['job']; ?>" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" name="freelancer" value="<?php echo $delivery['applicant_id']; ?>">

            <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['job']; ?>">

            <input type="hidden" name="delivery_id" value="<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>">

            <h4 class="font-16 font-600 m-0 my-2">What revisions would you like <?php echo $seller_name ?> to make?</h4>

            <textarea name="revision_details" placeholder="What you'de like to change will help the seller perfect your job." cols="30" rows="8" required class="form-control <?php echo isset($revision_errors['revision']) ? 'form-error' : ''; ?>"></textarea>

            <div class="form-errors-list filled"><?php echo $revision_errors['revision'] ?? ''; ?></div>

            <button type="submit" name="job-revision-submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary w-md waves-effect waves-light float-right">
                <span id="btnLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span>
                <span id="btnText">Send Revision Request</span>
            </button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#review_seller_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>').click(function() {
            $("#accept_review_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>").toggle();
            $("#revision_details_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>").hide();
        });
        $('#request_revision_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>').click(function() {
            $("#revision_details_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>").toggle();
            $("#accept_review_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

For displaying revisions I have selected revisions from the job revisions table for this job with the delivery id.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM job_revisions WHERE delivery_id = ? AND job_id = ?";` like so.

But I am still having trouble in fill those forms for Accept and Request Revision.

Does anyone have any experience with this, or any way to help me out? I'm just stumbling along here and want to learn!

Comment: What is 'posted by' in the job_applicants table?

Comment: @Strawberry it is user id of the user who posted the job.

Comment: So it simply repeats the information in the jobs table?

Comment: Yes, it is same id from the jobs table